# Adding Requird CSS Class to Images in WordPress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Using Custom Bootstrap and WordPress Theme I need to add/import a class called  `class="img-responsive"` to all images which are added/uploaded through Editor **Gallery** or **Feature Images**. Can you please le t me know how I can do this grammatically in function.php?
Thanks

Comment: is it ok to apply classes by arguments..? or by applying that classes to "img" tag, while we are fetching them through image source..?

Comment: Hi Karunal , well I think this is possible when querying the data by Wp-quwey but how about displaying a gallery? As far as I know the Galley can be retrieve through <?php the_content(); ?> is there any other way?

Comment: gallery means image gallery...right..?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35874/change-output-for-images-in-content

Answer (score 0):

**wordpress php function**

```
    function add_responsive_class($content){

        $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
        $document = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $document->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content));

        $imgs = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach ($imgs as $img) {           
           $img->setAttribute('class','img-responsive');
        }

        $html = $document->saveHTML();
        return $html;   
}
add_filter        ('the_content', 'add_responsive_class');
```

**or You can use jquery code on the header.php file of your theme.**

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
 $("img").addClass("img-responsive")
});
</script>
```